# sum of a range of a sum of a range of n

Tags: code-golf

In this challenge, your input is an integer value. Your task is to find the sum of the range of the sum of the range of n.

Examples:

```
Input -> Output
1     -> 1
2     -> 6
3     -> 21
4     -> 55
5     -> 120
6     -> 231
7     -> 406
8     -> 666
9     -> 1035
10    -> 1540
```

This challenge should be fairly simple to complete in most languages :) 
Have fun!

Comment: OEIS: [A002817](https://oeis.org/A002817)

Comment: Is the input an integer, or as in your example a strictly positive integer ?

Comment: `T_(T_n)`, where `T_n` is the `n`th triangle number.

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 17 bytes

```javascript
x=>(x*x-~x)**2>>3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY5DoAgEADAr2zJIcajVPgLQTBrCGvAGCq/jlQzl31tcRnvRyU6fAu6VW1YFVV9lQuxGLO2QBkYgoZ5A4S9O/VIycFRKhT9GOlkOEBgyHn7AQ)

Thanks [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for -1 byte.

Comment: `+x+1` can be `-~x` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 11):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 22 bytes

*With unsequenced modification and access to `n`*

```c
f(n){n*=~n;n=--n*n/8;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCsIwFEbhce4qfiqFpG18jYQ0XYkTSYxe0Bup1UmpW48dHfg4wd5CKCVpMbM0/idOvLXSyO7klrJhCY9PvKJ/T5Hz9j4QsUz0vLDob@ZoaCa1CtgRqZRHaIbHwYHRr907tC0bUuo1rlvSVW2PEXZAHc9SdeAOSbMxjpbyBw)

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 26 bytes

*With unsequenced modification and access to `n`*

```c
f(n){n*=~n;return--n*n/8;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpNCoMwEEDhdeYUg0VI1PRvVYh6km4kMe2AnZQ0diP26mlWDz6e1XaZ@JGzl6w2boYfmzinNbLW3PDpZvZ8ILbL6mbsP8lROD5HAOIEr4lYfgM5BRuIIkgGQPgQURIOeDFI2JeeDbYtKRDiHcvmZVXrq0M9Yu3uXHVIHXpJShnY8x8)

## [C89](http://clang.llvm.org/), 28 bytes

```c
f(n){n*=~n;return(n-2)*n/8;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY3LCoMwEADP2a9YLEKipg9Plqhf0oskxi7YtUTtReynN/U0MAyM1XbseIjRS1YbZ82XTeiXNbBkXaqML5XZ44nYjqvrsZ4XR9P52QIQL/DqiOVnIqdgA3EYJAMg/BRQEjZ4M0hYH7wazHNSIMQ7HJmXSapLh7rF1D04KZAK9JKUMrDHn/VjN8xRH7PGVvc/)

### Explanation

```c
f(n){n*=~n;return--n*n/8;}  // function which takes and returns an integer
     n*=~n;                 // n *= -(n + 1); here (n = -(n*n + n))
                 --n        // decrement n;   here (n = -(n*n + n + 1))
           return  n*n/8;   // return (n*n + n + 1)^2 / 8
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
#@*#&@Tr@*Range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X9lBS1nNIaTIQSsoMS899X9AUWZeiYK@Q7q@A1jAwdD0/38A)

-1 byte from @att

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
(f=Tr@*Range)@*f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277XyPNNqTIQSsoMS89VdNBK@1/QFFmXomCvkO6vgNY0MHQ9P9/AA)

Comment: `#@*#&@Tr@*Range`

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
+/∘⍳⍣2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1v/UceMR72bH/UuNvqf9qhtwqPevkddzY961zzq3XJovfGjtomP@qYGBzkDyRAPz@D/aYdWPOpdBdRhaAAA)

`+/` the sum

`∘` of

`⍳` the range

`⍣2` twice

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ x õ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=9SB4IPU&input=MTA)

Comment: Just that the number of bytes encoding-dependent, utf-8 would be 7 bytes ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Actually, Japt is designed to be used with this encoding specifically, as the interpreter can read those raw bytes as they are in that codepage

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 17 bytes

```hs
g.g
g n=sum[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzP10vnStdIc@2uDQ32lBPLy/2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQm5igUKaAkjO0CD2/7/ktJzE9OL/uskFBQA)

Just implementing the definition seems to be shorter than arithmetical expressions such as

**21 bytes**

```hs
f n=((n^2+n+1)^2-1)/8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz1ZDIy/OSDtP21AzzkjXUFPf4n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikJuYoFCmkK0oZ6eoUHs/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

With floats:

**17 bytes**

```hs
g.g
g n=n*(n+1)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzP10vnStdIc82T0sjT9tQU9/of25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQm5igUKaQrShnp6hQez/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 32 bytes

```
({({}[()])()}{})
({({}[()])()}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6Nao7o2WkMzVlNDs7a6VpMLXeD/f2MA)

(The newline isn't needed, but is included because it makes the answer pretty)

Polygonal numbers are one of the things that brain-flak uniquely excels at. This is just the code that calculates the N-th triangular number, repeated twice.

```
# Push (the sum of...)
(
    # While the top of stack is not 0...
    {
        # Decrement the top of the stack by 1
        # This adds n-1 to the running counter
        ({}[()])

        # Plus 1 (to the running counter)
        ()
    }

    # Pop the stack (which should contain a 0 now)
    {}
)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2 bytes (4 nibbles)

```
+,+,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWS7R1tHUgTKjIgoUmEAYA)

#### Explanation

```
+,+,$
    $  Input number (implicit)
   ,   Range from 1 to that number
  +    Sum
 ,     Range from 1 to that number
+      Sum
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Binary Lambda Calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html), 125 bits = 15.625 bytes

```
01000001 11001110 10000101 01100001 10010000 00000101 10011111 01110010
11110111 10110000 00001110 01011110 11010000 10110001 00000100 00010
```

[Verify it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVdRb9s2EH7bg37F1Q1gEbGNSMCAoo09pN0GdMiKAh32EhuFLFG2EFnSJCqx2_Rn7GkvfRn2n_prdnckJcpOtwEDgpg83n338Xg8nv74axs1tzLPP3_55ruP06dwHRWbNtpI-DGX-2ydy9dFo6Iilg08nX7ysl1V1gre1jJvEwnbLMmKjQfgQ7Ru8FdYjVdloeoyn11VVZ7FkcruJKvlWaquQhxO4CpXsi54CfzZTDxm_nNZRAkb3pVZwmZIr05c3e8jFZGiVvDBv1yIk_VX26jm1ay5yqttxFBm_KbdnehfZ41i_TQrktdFIvenLqPDWhrMn1pWn0Balzsz6bXlut3MfqmjWKsrMxKeV8h7dagkvI3qRtYQwRzlZuK_UzVGF6YLuDHjCURihWYRRvUAz5_3dqj0FXWj7BvVSkDDXir89bzMHC_82BaxKmuLeL-VNXFMd1EFKa65AGTe0TzTOj7_69SFgMpBd9Lg2EPV1hL2Q0wfltA422nMdvZiRVEDk0aQ9qwC0Y_DIUUewhFoUhoxLtRyF0yglg2CXE4Ry-gNNELWCLVGCGTTrddStXVh1VKG0tpGRTix4Jw-joKlDovFHAH-F_1j9iYBUqPiMHdpudfxiJzcVepwekLv-XDoRACcLQRw-bDoZuFxtgz30cUazs9J2UyE93HaU_P17cZshvkCzMSeNgotz51LlPNKS2gJgyCLxKyZ9DFCrGtejPXhJV8pn0oFUXtZlrmggXHEJcToVbVMKJ-le2E3dCaWC-AU_Aiew9pmI8AN-Gu6lPDgIESwsvoYzE51pUkRJcvomIi5NoaTv5_P8UBNBNGsLwjGUAusBpliKbqTuMYY5LDMMN5oe2Oju3LsI6tApmmZJ5gHeNZCJ8ifrUqnz754vydYHeE6hjn8ihxfF0pu0PgB35YdiR-oGtAA_xJZZ3dExn-3Le8n8MNvwptO4Q7tFnDhYYzaWAbgE1CGcYQ3pdrSHroVAlW0Eke4DStWUKbIkSoxqDFtgYdae0wJa4Bo6QST-GlVvC6Kqokxb9o1AQYQkHhooAKjOiQSuEwCh4q2GTPQgM7QPtT2FiE8QSCZLjOPbEkTtuHLkj0BziFLIYP5XAu2siCpzNEtL1z2cjbUSzT0M5hCICysiX0HS3MbI9RN9udUle9ldItQF7TTzlRzp_iEDgAH3gY5MHLRi0Ir8gxofpc7ycHsFyzs2PsZkeh2kA0su-Rh5mbFxyWyUUMvgzNmos6qcjbK8y47MBL_mptWczxMBOVRFcRLKusdgixx87JQ5zBjSYMXiQX467NAGF183_n33KPKpnX6XsEUAS2e40MCHyGmd8OUkb4peoEdAsp3UXHAuv3IsrMCYxi_6N7BGMteI-CTx9SpnGivbjG5jvUqE2mYCT3shgqVGU-XzO6p036Wy_GJZ6OA3dR7A2d583RgP_uqufatI4iPqi6MDia-UHpkX3W73QxtqJJTFiHIkyeQy2Kjto6xNpn0m2GKLrtcKs7ued9ygo93tBHGq9Hj_hd9cs9JFsdsOOtVaesuNmbYp-L18ympSV-ckNGB8P9TZAZktJ74qqHhlMc8p3eul2i4f0yO5ig7Tp3ksZujTkL1rnx6qfKA7yyqC68iH_j4DJ5I9Gjljb2xpnHSTG5W1Dnz1fVHowlCCcxy7oF4ezySdY099IiRII2yHJuQkeflcbjO2SHCd626FfcFzFdYQZAwfkTY40P5Ge6kkpGCcTAWlIWji1Fn25Ww0cXFiBbNguo0BoVrdBEMtAJ3ElIH0Ba3MuEYYDk1eYwxnsMzXVQbXUyZ6TPgWzECxrS2flKXFa1hN5JHu_dtlXCnBDbAo-WymmGfulzu4QDpjPr45XIDH2aAncAe_33A7wccoLTAxT1r8AjlBzFyYMNHcH20a9o4hh5eTxmUhwcEegRcI9f4ESybloqu_Z7jQ9D1-0xXf8ep2WAxgwLMGBnYfaEDcsybnbHjfjwS4GyFnWMU6xhLh3mVzsx_W2N0c0IZExISDfBaY8kpBtS719SBDLUzq4JnLeNbdmQeIMYeorj2BTrEguRIfArSTTCbgR0UK_w-xWQaEDH5NUD2dlFW2Htd4XXApiDKc9CkCOrbleDPQ4W35ZoeFZNeZ4_iiR7GJO2AhdDd6WfzY37_Bg)

Encodes the following lambda term:

```haskell
main = 2 rangesum where
  succ = \n f x. f (n f x)
  pair = \x y f. f x y
  snd = \p. p (\x y. y)
  update = \p. p (\x y f. f (succ x) (x succ y))
  rangesum = \n. snd (n update (pair 1 0))
```

This is a function that takes a positive integer in Church numeral and outputs the answer in the same form. The numbers that appear in the Haskell-like code above are also Church numerals, e.g. `2 = \f x. f (f x)`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｉ÷⍘12320Ｎ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzOvxCWzLDMlVcMpsTg1uAQok66hZGhkbGSgpKPgmVdQWuJXmpuUWqShqamjYKGpqWn9/7/Jf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   12320    Literal string `12320`
  ⍘         Interpret as base
        Ｎ   First input as a number
 ÷          Integer divide by
         ⁸  Literal integer `8`
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

The boring solution is 8 bytes:

```
ＩΣ…·Σ…·Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8MzLzmntDizLDUoMS89FZuQZ15BaYlfaW5SapGGJgRY//9v8l@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: `InclusiveRange` prefers two arguments, but fortunately we can arrange to use the one-argument version (twice, saving two bytes).

```
       Ｎ    First input as a number
     …·     Inclusive range from `1` to that
    Σ       Take the sum
  …·        Inclusive range from `1` to that
 Σ          Take the sum
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implcitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LOLO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx9/H//9/QwMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/i6mevpPCobZKCkr3ffx9/H///Ov8B).

**Explanation:**

```python
L     # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 O    # Sum this list together
  L   # Pop and push a list in the range [1, sum]
   O  # Sum this list together again
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Laughing Out Loud! Out??

An equal-bytes alternative could be: `2FLO`, where `2F` is loop 2 times:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyM3H//9/QwMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/i6mevpPCobZKCkr3ffyM3H///tTr/AQ).

Comment: I love that these make readable words

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ɾ∑ɾ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJBIiwiIiwiyb7iiJHJvuKIkSIsIiIsIjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjZcbjdcbjhcbjkiXQ==)

Uses the straightforward approach: `ɾ` gets the range from 1 through its argument, and `∑` sums. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
N=nn+n
f(n)=N(N+2)/8
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bn7v7e6r8o)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 19 bytes

```r
\(n)sum(1:sum(1:n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhabYzTyNItLczUMrSBknqYmROZmVpqGoaaCsoIhV5qGEYhhBmQYgxhGICETEMvUFMgyBasyMgAyzcDSxiB5cxDTxACkyQKs2wzEtASrNTAG6TM0AHNMTQwgNi5YAKEB)

Comment: [Attempt this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/) has a version of R that's on 4.3.0, so you can use it to include a link if you like.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
sSsS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzi4OPj/f0MDAA)

#### Explanation

```
sSsSQ    # implicitly add Q
         # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
   SQ    # range 1 to Q
  s      # sum
 S       # range 1 to result
s        # sum
```

Extra nice since when pronounced out loud it is the sound a python makes.

Answer (score 4):

## brainf**k, 110 bytes

```
,[>+>+>+<<<-]>>>[-[>+>+<<-]>>[-<<+>>]<<[-<+>]>[-<+>]<]<[>+>+>+<<<-]>>>[-[>+>+<<-]>>[-<<+>>]<<[-<+>]>[-<+>]<]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOGwRtbGx0Y@3s7KJ1oyFcEC9a18ZG284u1sYGyNK2i7WDUDaxNuTp0vv/3wQA)

Probably not the shortest implementation but I'm too lazy to make this shorter lol...

Like most other b****fuck programs, it doesn't output the answer. Instead, it prints the ascii character corresponding to the numeric answer.

Check [this](https://visual-brainfuck-web.netlify.app/) out to see the running process.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the test case to [this](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOGwRtbGx0Y@3s7KJ1oyFcEC9a18ZG284u1sYGyNK2i7WDUDaxNuTp0vv/nxUA) (where ascii 5 turns into x which is 120 in ascii), since when 4 is the input one expects 55 as the output, but your code returns 243

Comment: @CommandMaster Problem is, the code seems to tend to interpret numeric inputs as ascii values instead of their values. Try replacing "," with "++++" if you wanna test 4. You can view the running process on the online IDE I linked to.

Comment: By the way, I suppose this could be golfed to around 80 bytes or so by introducing an outer loop, but my brain is already scorched so I'll leave that up to the more f**kable brains ;-P

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 16 bytes

-2 byte thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh).

```
n->(1+n^2+n)^2\8
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWG_J07TQMtfPijLTzNOOMYiwgwjdV0vKLNPIUbBUMdRQMDXQUCooy80qAAkoKunZAIk0jT1NTE6J2wQIIDQA)

Comment: I know nothing about PARI/GP. But seems `n->(1+n^2+n)^2>>3` works.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 23 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to `c--`'s suggestion based on `tsh`'s answer.

```python
lambda n:(n*n-~n)**2//8
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhbbcxJzk1ISFfKsNPK08nTr8jS1tIz09S0gsjdV0vKLFPIUMvMUihLz0lM1DHUUDA01rbgUFAqKMvNKNNI08jQ1IWoXLIDQAA)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 38 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(range(sum(range(n+1))+1))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY31XISc5NSEhXyrIpLczWKEvPSUzUQrDxtQ01NEIaqVknLL1LIU8jMU4DIG-ooGBpqWnEpKBQUZeaVaKRp5MHULlgAoQE)

Comment: [23 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhbbcxJzk1ISFfKsNPK08nTr8jS1tIz09S0gsjdV0vKLFPIUMvMUihLz0lM1DHUUDA01rbgUFAqKMvNKNNI08jQ1IWoXLIDQAA) porting tsh's JS answer

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```java
n->(n=n*n-~n)*n/8
```

Port of [*@tsh*' JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260979/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well.
-1 byte thanks to *@tsh*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU5BDoIwELz7ig2nlgaUmxHrD@TC0XioBcwiLIQWEmPw67Ugl9ns7OzM1GpSUV28nG6UMXBVSJ8dAJIth0rpErJlXQnQbEHiqWfmnQdjlUUNGRBIR9GFkaSQoi/xkPZHly6afnw0XrNJpw4LaH0Iy@2A9LzdFf8HVN2w2qNMUsCzTA5@CMHXI0D@NrZs4260ce8fbUMMRXCCQFDse/Gt1Ox@)

`(n=n*n-~n)` could alternatively be `(n+=n*n+1)` for the same byte-count:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU4xDoMwDNx5hcWUEIGKupWGH5SFseqQBqhMwSASkKqKt6eBspzl8/nuWrWouK3eTnfKGLgppG8AgGTrqVG6hmJbdwI025B45pk18GCssqihAALpKM4ZCUkRiZRHlOdnl22icX52XnRolwEr6H0KK@2E9Lo/FP8nNMO0@6NMM8CrTE9@CMH3I0D5Mbbuk2G2yegfbUcMRXiBUFDii/Gj1ep@)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->               // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  (n=             //  Replace `n` with:
     n*n          //   `n` squared
        -~n)      //   `+n+1`
            *n    //  Square that new `n`
              /8  //  Integer-divide that by 8 to get the result
```

---

A literal implementation would be **56 bytes** in comparison:

```java
n->{int t=0;for(;n>0;)t+=n--;for(;t>0;)n+=t--;return n;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY69DoMwDIR3nsJiShSBYG0a3qAsjFWHlJ8qFAwKBqlCPDtNgOUsfyefr9WLjtrqu5edniZ4aINrAGCQatvosobcrweAknlFLh3ZAicTaTIl5ICgdoyy1fukEtkMlknMEslJKIyiE5AHKBQ5YGuaLQLKbZc@apzfnYu6EpfBVNC7Lqwga/DzfGl@9vBB/otRqQRzV2nihhD8MAGK30R1Hw8zxaM7pA6ZEeENQoGxq8@v7tv@Bw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{          // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int t=0;    //  Temp-integer, starting at 0
  for(;n>0;)  //  Loop `n` down until it's 0:
    t+=n      //   Add the current `n` to the temp-integer `t`
        --;   //   And then decrease `n` by 1
              //  (at this point, `n=0`)
  for(;t>0;)  //  Now loop `t` down until it's 0:
    n+=t      //   Add the current `t` to `n`
        --;   //   And then decrease `t` by 1
  return n;}  //  Return the modified `n` as result
```

Comment: Maybe you can write `/8` instead of `>>3` in Java.

Comment: @tsh I indeed can. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>41</s> 37 bytes

```go
func(n int)int{n=n*n-^n
return n*n/8}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BTcWCxOTsxPRUhdzEzDyuzNyC_KISPaW03BIlLq6yxCKFNNulpSVpuhY3VdNK85I18hQy80o0gbg6zzZPK083Lo-rKLWktChPAcjTt6iFKrYAKQYbqaGpUM2Vll-kkGlla2itkGljaAAktbWBogFFQHNy8jQydRTSNDI1NblquaD6FyyA0AA)

- -4 bytes by @c--

Comment: @c-- In Go, the tilde is not used as bitwise negation like in other languages; instead it's used for type constraints (`~A` is "types that have underlying type A"). Try running your own port and look at the compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 21 bytes

```hs
t n=sum[1..sum[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0Qhz7a4NDfaUE8PSuXFxv7PTczMsy0oyswrUclNLFAoiTbQ07OM/Q8A)

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, 13 bytes

```
00000000: 8ad8 43f6 e340 f7e0 b103 d3e8 c3         ..C..@.......
```

Listing:

```
8A D8       MOV   BL, AL        ; BL = x 
43          INC   BX            ; BL = x + 1 
F6 E3       MUL   BL            ; AX = x * (x + 1) 
40          INC   AX            ; AX = x * (x + 1) + 1 
F7 E0       MUL   AX            ; AX = AX * AX 
B1 03       MOV   CL, 3 
D3 E8       SHR   AX, CL        ; AX = AX >> 3
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable with input `n` in `AL`, output in `AX`.

Uses the formula `(x*(x+1)+1)^2>>3`.

[image]

Comment: 186 and later can use `shr ax, 3` (3 bytes).  (If you meant to stick to a tighter restriction of only 8088/8086 instructions, I assume you would have said that instead of x86-16, which includes modern x86 in 16-bit mode.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 16 bytes

```
!n=(n^2-~n)^2÷8
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FhsU82w18uKMdOvyNOOMDm-3gAjvScsvUsi0NbQyNOBSUCgoyswrycnTUMzU5ErNS4EogZkAAA)

The formula looks a bit shorter than directly writing out the sums.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 18 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∑1..∑1..&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?xCX3JW)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 21 bytes

```
[ [1,b] Σ [1,b] Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeUmJeeWgxhl@ZlJuenpCoUpxaWpuYlA4ULilJLSioLijLzShSsubgMDRSiDXWSYv9HQ2iFc4sRjNj/uYkFCnr/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
‼Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDnnOL////bwoA)

```
‼         # Apply function twice:
Σ         # Triangular number
```

(the more-boring [`ΣΣ`](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zic4v///9vCgA) is also 2 bytes...)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 65 bytes

`f(n){int i=10;for(;i>1;)n+=i--;for(;n>1;)i+=n--;printf("%d",i);}`

### Earlier attempts

#### 73 bytes

`main(){int i=0,n=10;for(;n>0;)i+=n--;for(;i>0;)n+=i--;printf("%d\n",n);}`

#### 70 bytes

`main(n){int i=10;for(;i>1;)n+=i--;for(;n>1;)i+=n--;printf("%d\n",i);}`

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to Bubbler

```
i:1+*2,:1+*2,n;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaToxKyo6MisqOCxuOyIsImlucHV0IjoiMyIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

Just the triangle number formula copied twice

Comment: 13 bytes: `i:1+*:2+*8,n;` using the formula expanded as `n(n+1)(n(n+1)+2)/8`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 bytes

```
RSRS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UqpS7IKlpSVpuhZLgoKDgpcUJyUXQwUWLLSAMAA)

Range, sum, range, sum.

Comment: Nice one! You can also add the `S` flag and drop the last `S`.

Comment: @TheThonnu Good point, I don’t think I’ll go through and edit my answer though, as this is such a trivial challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>68</s> 54 bytes

```
listen to N
cast N
let N be*N+1
let X be N+2
say N*X/8
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Saved 12 byes thanks to [c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)'s suggestion to use a different formula.

Comment: idk rockstar but this seems to work for 56 bytes:
`listen to N`
`cast N`
`let N be N*N+N`
`let M be N+2`
`say N*M/8`

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 24 bytes

```lua
print((...^2-~...)^2//8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ09PL85Itw5IacYZ6etbaP7//9/QAAA)

Based off [tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260979/117588), though it's been modified a bit to better fit Lua.

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)*

```
+´⟜↕⍟2
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes a number and returns a number. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgK8K04p+c4oaV4o2fMgoKRsKoIDHigL8y4oC/M+KAvzTigL814oC/NuKAvzfigL844oC/OeKAvzEw)

#### Explanation

Same idea as [Adám's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260968/16766), slightly complicated by the fact that BQN's ranges are 0-based.

Call the argument N:

```
+´⟜↕⍟2
   ↕     Range (0 to N-1)
+´       Fold on addition...
  ⟜     ... with a starting value of N
    ⍟2  Apply that function twice
```

Comment: `+´⟜↕⍟2` (`+´⟜↕x`=`x+´↕x`)

Comment: @att Oh, that's clever. I often forget that folds and scans can be dyadic.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 19 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
1$`
1
1$`
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLy5DLUCUBRv7/b8hlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWUJAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1
1$`
```

Sum of range.

```
1
1$`
```

Sum of range.

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 4 bytes

```
RSRS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FkuCgoOClxQnJRdDBZZFKxkaKMVCeQA)

Nobody golfing in Jelly anymore?

Comment: Polyglots with Thunno 2!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 bytes

```
△△
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//0bTNQPT/vxkA)

Uses the built-in for triangle number twice. Implicit input and output.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

```
2{x+/!x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxlkMtuwjAQRffzFa5aVa2q4EdiAxnRrrvqByAkXOMEBMRp7EhBiH57nVTJBm/uufYZL6bIxbV7ow/djQKE/Pq0vvw2eUEI6XDrjviyLfThhB1esHnd3CCsOfJNDIGqjxTFUDOUsk+JXLAeFIp0eJljxgZ1gUoNsETO0sHmDLnMog8U9iHUPqfUuJ0t3amY+aDN0XZmr6vSzow705/W+nBwladCsaVS1LfnxBWJTpre+cf7u+qj1qVdieegv1feuMburDePsSXB1QCfVd0GkryTrzZEAk76EzsHMaKCdETBIRtZSpCTLRioSUo5zMcSFwCL6SelYDnNxEUAZ2OLuwD4A0iFaKc=)

- `2{...}/` set up a monadic do-reduce, running the code in `{...}` twice

  - `!x` generate `0..x-1`
  - `x+/` set up a plus-reduce (i.e. sum) seeded with the input `x`

Comment: Tacit: ```2(+/!1+)/```.  No shorter though.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
=A1*(A1+1)/8*(A1^2+A1+2)
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 6 bytes

```
R&+R&+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z9ITRuI/v83BwA)

A pretty direct mapping of the rules of the contest to Ly instructions for this one...

```
R      - Generate range of numbers from 0 to STDIN
 &+    - Sum the stack
   R   - Generate range of numbers again, from 0 to top-of-stack
    &+ - Sum the stack
       - Top of stack printed as a number be default on exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒Σ╒Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1EnnFoOJ//8NuYy4jLlMuEy5zLjMuSy4LLkMDQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒     # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 Σ    # Sum it together
  ╒   # Pop and push a list in the range [1, sum]
   Σ  # Sum it together again
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 25 bytes

```php
fn($n)=>($n**2-~$n)**2>>3
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724IKNgwUobeyDFpZJmu7S0JE3XYmdanoZKnqatHZDU0jLSrQNygLSdnTFEfo11anJGvkqahqGBpjVEaMECCA0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 15 bytes

```
?22)d**2'd')2p@
```

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=3#%3F22)d**2%27d%27)2p%40)!

Just the code for "sum range" twice.

Answer (score 1):

## SAS 4GL, 22 <s>23</s> bytes

The code:

```
o=n*(n+1)*(n*n+n+2)/8;
```

The code plus "environment" and nice printout:

```
data;
  do n = 1 to 10;
    o=n*(n+1)*(n*n+n+2)/8;
    put n "-> " o;
  end;
run;
```

The log:

```
1    data;
2      do n = 1 to 10;
3        o=n*(n+1)*(n*n+n+2)/8;
4        put n "-> " o;
5      end;
6    run;

1 -> 1
2 -> 6
3 -> 21
4 -> 55
5 -> 120
6 -> 231
7 -> 406
8 -> 666
9 -> 1035
10 -> 1540
NOTE: The data set WORK.DATA4 has 1 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```
func a[I](n:I):I=(n*n+n)*(n*n+n+2)/8
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3VdJK85IVEqM9YzXyrDw1rTxtNfK08rTzNLUgtLaRpr4FVK1CWn6RQp5CZp6CoZ6eoYEVl0Jqcka-QqJGnl5aTn5iiSZEHcxsAA)

Takes and returns a float (so I can use `/` instead of `div`).

Answer (score 1):

## SAS IML, 18 bytes

The code:

```
o=sum(1:sum(1:n));
```

The code plus "environment" and nice printout:

```
proc IML;
  do n= 1 to 10;
    o=sum(1:sum(1:n));
    print n " => " o;
  end;
quit;
```

The log:

```
1    proc IML;
NOTE: IML Ready
2      do n= 1 to 10;
3        o=sum(1:sum(1:n));
4        print n " => " o;
5      end;
6    quit;
NOTE: Exiting IML.
NOTE: PROCEDURE IML used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Output:

[image: SAS IML Output]

Acknowledgement:

Thank you to Mr. [Roman Czyborra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58925/roman-czyborra) for the Haskel inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

## [minigolf](https://github.com/jfioasd/minigolf/), 7 bytes

```
2,,n;+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Rprk9u28Tt/Bawb1@RJp5N0tuPKd5lx7KZOq9Tu2U3dKhoFR0In2BTB8CFL6fS3u4sF@AYpneOZtjO58YwhAvvAvnfJcJ@sRXDxiW9CESUk3seWXm5oss7WNLoNaRQzy4IDw5glEXPTKOYi8PmGJ/aYXF6Si5FDTsgz3xcficdYyCKij20Zcanvx0PLQjQRucpRDp9Ft@mGBclr3LE9FrsRDxPAfdXb8IDfCn/Vc6wTokCH1POWVMPYD1bcZw8GsNv2l@xDBuTiJHIy6jUUZ1tAYAKlruQCgHtxIiK2TKKU9cxH18wP5cHXEQ9AdJptsmUoJGKvRETcNXM/8OCWPHv7iqShRxMWO71Wrtwvx9WrNAnThPg8TohYEVd4LBTAaEwo/JOyAbbaOUm@ICeBvychCuntqzeEJiRZM8ICT/LFdmAuEqVkBejHAKE5wv8kT7ENe3wlzScebqdIDPHZve1o@Bgg5RO2A6McOZa8qSTb632aDAbB0/7yE6ytOKHuB3g@XwCuAEQT5z/kykYjTzweDCNGPdvp934EnoZx6ANaXFtSoZzwAP7F8@nZeKFYAc58FtjcIV@T0TQXBXiBtHm2pT7s5Y/htDRPW2475AqtdFqRn@JuSMMQZGRLBdobGtoi8gaI1HEKbMyPWRc0ni9dGLGpX/njJfd2sDWyLI@tlPBtKURHIY5YnPqJEpYisASWEUD@jFHWuET5eLuBEhILwJYiMPgyMi0BhaPGODyW8ngwfzDNiPSvyLhyiPn5scWDacPsNNhZHaxCVkKPpkaTVXetiD4uSbv8V7p38Qj45ZVHrggSHqTMMt7yhHzDbkFUuXNqt7QMd2qIAhmY96ymaHpPewRNVa6XPUkHrrME9VQQJGwTFmrN/j6uIbpqQczBxsk9QDLoNeWVgWuZhSK0nQXp4/PKYR9OlQ9VNgXEgmiZ4fKNCPJ7LQ1slBCAiOa9UW9hde0/re1XVV6cdo5noYqi1@85dzmCLgwqQtIdrEEMKbxMOpjanjZMq6GtGvGnmjich6MmTBFL0ijQoUBtauJ6Rz1TAWPl0ySB@Edb4kXOL502giDHCCj9zMSxVFiGnXfFvIagWljdLuN0kzOaRPvGldW@zicuC5tCyeMxIhtQCA@IO8v/MiMma77a2zsnzw942Z3hsjp3wNbX4N/TjMi4Zh36sYq41fsDht2RwMgnJrTlzd5@NyAxCzWPMpjAr/lI6UxI9c0XNQW@a9paXFWEyHQwX3TpS8jAYlaXyDQF9Yg9e/lmQK5fvqkJEh47MixVRakRwCbEEAAyyEpUw11@MYBpuYfigysunDotzWwS0SAOBfjKrM4pCBS1DrG93ZJ8urnxKNlNyXy3GMw0HZGlazwCi8EvPLRPZ1n616YjED9oX54XmQILBrFQYh5sfkt9Wc3TiCecSYX/C4/2ppAhxqqE653iGqIRVPtQqE2kUVCZxP29OtA/dCAtYYthPdHrbWl9lSF5SQMPsk2Bg@hsqM5dlmBOSnhFab0vre@Xzp8fpDFUB@/Jg9a/QTCuC0KZjADmBxbtScBdhjYSiw0j0rchNQ@VyqMUAh5YH2poQGRBPBkQWUZdTLQN3PrihvpQMLvln1iGlh8UNVgtvNNanCgFTFkPwK30OaXP4Qe2h0IZn0u7QEIOucz253xRtfETcp16XJb7FC773QbigssTxU/toJ3QD2AxuopMAw@6OVnDKxqVw5L995hTaHDL7II4OSux5TST6Al5LsI9KgaR/MR/gg4iYqY6DsttVcR2FHN5xS@rmH5J8tWCsh6cGuCK0rxQ1KIdXVGBY1XdNxWieTFaFN9X5SuZ2alhxnq9I52CPL@noSwDVUk5rCBdyxodohKEC1jNx9NFvdpZZ5WERuQLEbapQpvaEZr4nxVlo7jFehQZMxStpjKnxhLqA7AUiQoECZGcMOqujVwpksptIHDJ9hYe9ceOYzXOSwfZLakvQ4/8r9pvSbIt/Q2ELa5hBgqDc0QjVJKDgRm1q49m1WKjaVMGNUeDApPsxlJterlTJlvqc3aI7XUar8nOakW2MwNPEdhLw3ZI/CHDhxlDrC7zkRpQSKhBtpwsMmOS60Fxwoh2i2jFttYNmDibtHB2D1HMxC13IcUEAicvw3Z0Y4jOzQK2rHYznd8hnefU93G0c14sP/JkLQc2Q8vkGIVgywHrBY@Ym@DYkHw8B7bVxKdhKhRb7@F76JjRSNx1NKjyarJ71c1Qp26bqvtCxpFpmcsb0pJ/ytO6o8KvY017plnWr5Wx4xzNlh2qiGTiFqF0ei6CKmo1H6s4bmMbq8K3UcqM9E6R3ib1Qa26C7uDLtGFHTArE2jD/rIur8Xiyop6saced8FIYnY4H42nbSnjuBKiwejZ2Bwv28uIBopmDnSOyVKt@e/zc@ARebCm5IlByZiqpKa34Lwi4r8w8@B4QG6qzjPo9CT0DXN6rZTJN@33i3KRk1NCHeugaiJDdsvsDsRZXJUCwpvD@Er3AwBzFi15XB89DhpO8Lg43dzd2wAIQCFxJBj36ziyANUldjlml5jni@nh@40cg7gyTin2vvdM4x2zsHD04rQqYPICBC9vaPOsV8kb7yN0q2Y/RatOHVMm@C2k/B@FlOsBmd01pNRsAqdMA3LttHn@3Zy8f9jJ76uWSnipL4jtCeirZX2W37TK9l2uWOFqRu7DrYwcnPdUsbXl6j3lIR5OyKuocDWMvFJJtcLsuiOwZCq/bhn3Nrgv3PT687x09JuX/jovnR3IEzVjOz9HazOZW4DmJl9EMqhcwXpkB0w4VLCQqybtFhyYrZcWPZ8c2G2pn7J2JHDEjCZVaESI3UoiJLKqQatxYFkGJjwc8UTs55TFCQnYDopzd@9CfnKMozRwnlDyfjbOdUd4TKCcT/aNXumwrXbaqNk272yTh2zx7jbYNscqyVVoucqvKZhuLoF@jfzsiKAzOzbo4NBBUwSbPq4@qPkBMGi2kz3eZ0JOT2ujiq4rVJAj7MyM/UT1@yy4hQZWrKS8Po@IVN2sJXNdqTfJP6fU58neumuVdLe5bVfcPTIxHxtv/ytDxhqnlVZdjfgPzV4utc7jmCRrGgzJG6j5aURE4O@/TA0h2ZqRy2p1pDmAzqs3Gk8uHj56/NWT3yMrGNciFodQRsjPvzx@y5Nu7LzyKUuO@Nk3z1/84ds/vkS04xEUguOvOoZXI3C7Ama44vhW0TEJ7TtEedGRdi4mRsA/Kf/tUOJkZLzLn2ff/@XV679ev3mLGM7wOmdjq8Pi8T4luM4b/Q3RjoaP2jHCphH0B3WnR487LvXosRH071o1oy61jIyg7zTo5GEX7OShEfgfCnjypAN28sQI@s@M5W6egWmrmMnhp0ulr89cHM2qT@vUi5WYrCKxMXxnZ9UmGPnEAike/y1Evp@9S85apa@voCduhlmgKCePeqQmp@eNMzvzXCV/d8dbq2fk5H1HRs1JNEb5chT63nE@p4zOkQEOoG4YouYft/wYlKav@sW6mGYjWQGhb3dcYi9Q1sa56nVEx8coZWYzp83egEVoSrLZ0hPY/HsBNK@SQEsDXPUGoklNfwNZuTIY5UC/Y3U@jUf/AQ)

### Explanation

```
2,    _  Repeat 2 times:
  ,n;    Generate a [1..n] range
     +   Sum it

Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 13 bytes

```lua
(n^2-~n)^2//8
```

Direct port of [bluswimmer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/117588/bluswimmer)'s [port](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260986/58375) of [tsh's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260979/117588), utilising ARBLE's more terse extensions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/18jL85Ity5PM85IX9/i////hgYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 23 bytes

```
$0=int((1+$0^2+$0)^2/8)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcA2M69EQ8NQW8UgzghIaMYZ6Vto/v9vyGXEZcxlwmXKZcZlzmXBZcllaAAA)

---

This will also work if the input is 0 (<s>28</s> thank to @Dominic van Essen 24 bytes):

```
$0=int((1+$0^2+$0)^2/8)a
```

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcA2M69EQ8NQW8UgzghIaMYZ6VtoJv7/b8BlyGXEZcxlwmXKZcZlzmXBZcllaAAA) to print if input is zero, I think...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen you are right ! Didn't bother too much with the second one as I didn't get an answer from OP

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)/[Zsh](https://https://zsh.org), 19 bytes

```bash
$[($1**2-~$1)**2/8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fJVpDxVBLy0i3TsVQE0jrW8T@///fCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 15 bytes

```
-8!*/0 2+*/0 1+
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxlkF1PgzAUhu/Pr6jRGHVh/YB2wMn02it/wLJklRW2bKNIS8Ji9LdbMHCzXvQ8b/u0F2+ZR+ndC2VELIadLwB8/v2wuf62eUkI6XFnT/i0K/XxjD1esX3e/oDfcOTbMASqYcQoxpiglMOUyAUbQKGIx5sVJmxUU1RqhAw5i0ebM+QyCT5QOHjfuJzSwu5NZc/l0nldnExfHHRdmWVhL/SrM84fbe2oUCxTirruEtky0lE7OP94e1a/Nboya/Ho9efaFbY1e+OK+5AibxuA97rpPIleyUfnAwEnwwqZg5hQQTyh4JBMLCXI2RYM1CzFHFZTCAVAOv+kFGTzm1AEcDal0AXAHwT9aHQ=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

The following is probably the most direct approach to the problem given Ruby's basic methods.

```ruby
->(n){(1..(1..n).sum).sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9dOI0@zWsNQTw@E8zT1iktzwUTt/4LSkmKFND2N9NSSYr2S/PhMzf/GAA)

***Another idea:*** Let *T(n)* be the *n*-th triangular number. Our answer is *T(T(n))* - we're interested in the *T(n)*-th triangular number.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), 21 bytes

```
$0*=$0+1,$0*=($0+2)/8
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhZbVQy0bFUMtA11QAwNIMtIU98CIgdVsmCLIZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOZcFlyWXoQFEDgA)

Given a positive integer as input, the following happens in sequence:

- The pattern `$0*=$0+1` is tested. `$0` initially contains the input number `n`, and is overwritten to `n^2+n`. Since this is nonzero, the pattern is matched, and a "range match" starts.
- The pattern `$0*=($0+2)/8` is tested. `$0` is overwritten to `(n^2+n)(n^2+n+2)/8`. Since this is nonzero, the pattern is also matched, and the "range match" ends immediately.
- The default action is performed, which is to print `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 4 bytes

Explanation:

```
     # inclusive range
     # sum range
     # inclusive range
     # sum range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCR1AvAZG//9vCQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 25 bytes

Saved 1 byte(s) thanks to the comment of @Jo King ♦

---

What's it?

Accroding to [A002817](https://oeis.org/A002817), doubly triangular numbers are revealed in the sums of row sums of Floyd's triangle.

```
1, 1+5, 1+5+15, ...
             1
          2     3
       4     5     6
    7     8     9     10
11    12    13    14    15
```

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xC8JADIX3/opHp7ul6GjhCo4OTuIkIrHWUu3lyjUKIv3tZ2wzfMlLHknGmnpK4fpoasGeOsY3A27NHV6FodiOJbYx0ud0kNhxe7YljtwJnDqzN/WQcsfiKoX2ErvKrCFhBtgW48vPSNAYdIX0bMzqP93YwtNgZEmXQsJyQ/VzqUyO3Fr9aMqm9AM)

```scala
n=>(1 to(1 to n).sum).sum
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDsIwDET3foXVyVkiGInEwMjAhDohhEwpVaBxqsQMCPXbQ0hYnn26Ozv2NFFK/voYeoEDWYZPA3Ab7uCyQApjNLALgd6nowTL41kZ6NgKbEuyZgXZwJ5FFWYL1yD@T1Y6vlxBKcz5jEyMuPq5G6UdzSh1XLT4@ifrZ92whVapXF2aJaUv)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def t(n: Int): Int = (1 to (1 to n).sum).sum
    println((0 to 9).map(t).map(_.toString).mkString(" "))
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need the space after the first `to`

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 12 bytes

```ruby
(:+|:sum)**2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWazSstGusiktzNbW0jCBCywoU3KJNYyGcBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## AArch64 machine code, 20 bytes

```
00: 9b000000  madd x0, x0, x0, x0 // x = x * x + x
04: d341fc00  lsr x0, x0, #1      // x = x / 2
08: 9b000000  madd x0, x0, x0, x0 // x = x * x + x
0c: d341fc00  lsr x0, x0, #1      // x = x / 2
10: d65f03c0  ret
```

simple :)

use it as a function `uint64_t f(uint64_t x)`. will overflow on inputs > 92681.

you could also use it as `main` (not `_start` unless you replace the `ret` with an `exit` syscall) and its input will be the argument count including the program name.

Comment: I guess simple "x^2+x; halve by shift; x^2+x; halve by shift" has the same byte count?

Comment: yeah you're right, and it takes a higher input before overflowing too, 92681 is the max instead of 65535. i actually had a comment that i deleted saying "wait maybe i copied the wrong formula". i think i'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Moonscript](https://moonscript.org)/[Yuescript](https://yuescript.org), 18 bytes

```
(n)->(n^2-~n)^2//8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PzytOLsosKPn/v6AoM69EQUMjT1PXTiMvzki3Lk8zzkhf30JTwej/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) + `math`, 38 bytes

```rkt
(sum(range(+(sum(range(+(read)1)))1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE5nBpFKUWlmYWpSpo5OflVOpm5inkJpZkKBSX5mpq/tcAUhpFQNWpGtoo7KLUxBRNQ01NMP7/39DAAAA)

Although it's verbose and a bit slow, it's shorter than placing in the actual equation and/or using `apply +` instead of `sum`, and it doesn't cheat by using `triangle-number`:

- 43 bytes + faster

  ```rkt
  ((λ(f)(f(f(read))))(λ(n)(/(*(+ n 1)n)2)))
  ```

  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4WhonNutkaapkQaERamJKZpAABLK09TQ19DS0FbIUzDUzNM0Agr//28JAxZQYA4BZmBgCgImQGBsbGxkZAgA)
- 46 bytes, no `math` import

  ```rkt
  (apply +(range(+(apply +(range(+(read)1)))1)))
  ```

  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4WgkFhTkVCpoaxQBBVM1tDH4RamJKZqGmppg/P@/IRAAAA)
- 36 bytes, using `triangle-number` from `math`, it's fast and -2 bytes, but might be somewhat cheating?

  ```rkt
  ((λ(t)(t(t(read))))triangle-number)
  ```

  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE5nBpFKUWlmYWpSpo5OflVOpm5inkJpZkKJQUZQIV5aTq5pXmJqUWaWr@19A4t1ujRFOjBAiLUhNTNIEAXdX//5YwYAEF5hBgBgamIGACBMbGxkZGhgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__IyBTaW5nbGUtYnl0ZSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgZW5jb2RpbmcgZm9yIFVpdWEgMC44LjAKIyBXcml0dGVuIGhhc3RpbHkgYnkgVG9ieSBCdXNpY2stV2FybmVyLCBAVGJ3IG9uIFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlCiMgMjcgRGVjZW1iZXIgMjAyMwojIEFQTCdzICLijbUiIGlzIHVzZWQgYXMgYSBwbGFjZWhvbGRlci4KCkNPTlRST0wg4oaQICJcMOKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNtVxu4o214o21XHLijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbUiClBSSU5UQUJMRSDihpAgIiAhXCIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0-P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX7ijbUiClVJVUEg4oaQICLiiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYXiiaDiiaTiiaXDl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4oSC4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmtwqTii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHii5XiiY3iip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_imIfihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipfiiKfiiLXiiaHiip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziipDii4XiipniiKnCsOKMheKNnOKKg-KqvuKKk-KLlOKNouKsmuKNo-KNpOKGrOKGq-Kags63z4DPhOKInuK4ruKGkOKVreKUgOKVt-KVr-KfpuKfp-KMnOKMn-KVk-KVn-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)</sup>, 9 bytes

```
⍥(/++1⇡)2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAg4o2lKC8rKzHih6EpMgoKZiAxCmYgNApmIDcK)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=sum -p`, 19 bytes

```perl
$_=sum 1..sum 1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4NFfBUE8PSqnE//9v@i@/oCQzP6/4v66vqZ6BoQGQ9sksLrGyCi3JzAFp@K9bAAA)

Answer (score -1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Rss`, 0 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJSc3NBIiwiIiwiIiwiIiwiMVxuMlxuM1xuNFxuNVxuNlxuN1xuOFxuOSJd)

That's right - with the power of subscription models, this task can be done in 0 bytes!

*but how does Really Simple Syndication help you sum a range twice?*

Well technically speaking it doesn't - of course there's no rss feed involved. What's happening is that the `R` flag coerces numbers to ranges when an iterable is needed, and the two `s` flags sum the top of the stack at the end of execution. Due to the way the flag handler is implemented, duplicate flags apply the flag effect multiple times.

Comment: I'd say the code is the flags in this case so 3 bytes

Comment: You might say so but site consensus says otherwise

Comment: By that logic `python -c "print('hello world')"` is also 0 bytes. If the program is entirely flags then the flags is the program

Comment: That's never happened with all the other 0 byters I've submitted

Comment: Most others didn't chain multiple operators. I think those are cheaty too but in those cases the flags are not literally just multiple instructions run in sequence like a program would run

Comment: we'll have to agree to disagree then

Comment: @mousetail, the consensus is [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/58974) if you want to argue against it, rather than in the comments of individual solutions adhering to that consensus.

Comment: I don't think this answer is against any existing rule (what makes the flags cheaty is too subjective), just that's it's cheaty and uninteresting, while a vyxal flags only answer would actually be interesting and worth a vote

Comment: @mousetail this _is_ a flags only program - `R` is a behavioural flag which changes how numbers are converted to iterables (usually it's list of digits, but with R it's range) and the two `s` are output flags. It's interesting because uses a little known quirk of the flag handler, which is that duplicate flags aren't stripped and applied in the for loop that applies output flags.

Comment: The R flag is fine. changing the behavior of the program is a legitimate use for flags, but the `s` flag actually performs a action which in my opinion is cheating. Any actions should be performed by the program.

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18382/43319

Comment: Might be of relevance: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/78410

Comment: @Aconcagua that's for languages made up specifically to solve a challenge or imaginary languages that don't exist. Vyxal has been around since 2020 and the flags since 2020 (s flag) and at least early 2021 (R flag).

Comment: Corner case, your language is not Vyxal, but Vyxal with `Rss` flags according to the consensus referenced by @Shaggy – if that now matches the loophole or not, well, that's not me to decide ;)

Comment: See my meta answer here: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25777/20080

Comment: @mousetail To play devil's advocate to your last point: Implicit input is bog standard in golfing langs now. That goes against the idea that "Any actions should be performed by the program." Implicit output is also run of the mill, from which the `s` flag is arguably a natural extension for a stack-based language.

Comment: @AviFS Taking input from the stack is a allowed input method, so implicit input simply converts between one type of allowed input method and another, and is thus perfectly fine

Comment: @mousetail Continue in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)?